# Hive and primary key constraint

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform, beeline, sqlline

The following HQL is generating an error on HDP 2.6.1 & Hive 1.2.1000. Is it a beeline issue or the Hive version?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nwdb.strings` (`string_id` INT, `string_data` STRING, PRIMARY KEY(string_id) DISABLE NOVALIDATE) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION "/data/nwdb/";
```

Error

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:133 cannot recognize input near 'KEY' '(' 'string_id' in column type (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Even ALTER command gives the same error

```
ALTER TABLE `aravind_stg_platform_nw_northwind_nwdb.strings` ADD CONSTRAINT string_id_PK PRIMARY KEY (`string_id`);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the support for primary keys and foreign is from Hive 2.1

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13290